# Get id from database (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get id of interviewer by his FIO

I have table with this model

```
 [Key]
    public int Interwier_id { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public int Birthday { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Interview_Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Current_work { get; set; }
    public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday; } }
    public virtual Interview Interview { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I get Name from text field like this

`interwierName: $("#name").text()`

And here back-end code

```
 public ActionResult AddComment(string name,string commentText, string interwierName)
    {
        var Id = db.InterwierModels
            .Where(x => x.FIO == interwierName)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x.Interwier_id
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        //var idForCreating = Int32.Parse(Id.ToString());

        Comment cmnt = new Comment()
        {
            Author = name,
            Comment1 = commentText,
            Interview_Id = Id
        };
        db.Comments.Add(cmnt);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
    }
```

But I have this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int ID>' to 'int?'  SmartSolutions  C:\Users\Eugene\Source\Repos\SmartWeb\SmartSolutions\Controllers\InterwierController.cs 52  Active

How I can fix it?

Comment: Because `Id` is an object containing a property named `ID` (not an `int`). Use `.Select(x => x.IInterwier_id).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
var Id = db.InterwierModels
            .Where(x => x.FIO == interwierName)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x.Interwier_id
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

With

```
    var Id = db.InterwierModels
                .Where(x => x.FIO == interwierName)
                .Select(x => x.Interwier_id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank's for help!